# How do you get the recipient or sender in reply message in outlook 365 add-in

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

When a task pane is opened from a new message or a reply message, how do i get the from and to.

While opened in compose mode Office.context.mailbox.item.from/to do not have any information similar to when opened from a received message

For example compose console log

```
OSF_InitializationHelper$loadAppSpecificScriptAndCreateOM.$h.ComposeRecipient {_type$p$0: 0, _propertyName$p$0: "to"}
    _propertyName$p$0: "to"
    _type$p$0: 0
    __proto__: Object
```

While the receive message is this

```
to: Array(1)
 OSF_InitializationHelper$loadAppSpecificScriptAndCreateOM.$h.EmailAddressDetails {$$d__getRecipientType$p$0: ƒ, $$d__getAppointmentResponse$p$0: ƒ, 
    $$d__getDisplayName$p$0: ƒ, $$d__getEmailAddress$p$0: ƒ, _data$p$0: {…}, …}
```

I'm pretty sure that at some point I was able to get details on from / to from compose.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the from address refer the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.from?view=office-js

To get the recipient refer to the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.recipients?view=office-js#getasync-options--callback-

Comment: The links are broken